# Microsoft Project Siena - How to make button1 navigate to a certain page if text1 equals "XX"?

Tags: project-siena

Microsoft Project Siena - How to make button1 navigate to a certain page if text1 equals "XX"?

---

Hello everyone,

So what I want is when you click a 'button' it will navigate to a page where you can enter in a password aka text in (for example the 'text1' field) then on the same page will be a 'button', when you click the 'button' it will check to see if there is certain text in 'text1' and if the text matches it will navigate to whatever page I want it to.

Is any of this possible?

If so, how exactly?

Keep in mind I would like to do this while inside of 'Microsoft Project Siena' meaning I do not have any other 'app' making tools installed currently.

Thank you and kinds regards,
-Sean D.

---

### ::UPDATE::

Some things I have already tried on my own:

I have another button that changes the visibility to true once a timer equals 5000, so I tried the same type of thing but it doesn't seem to be changing the visibility when the correct text is entered, for example:

```
If(Text1!Text!Value=test1234, true)
```

not even this works:

```
If(Text1!Value=test1234, true)
```

That is what I have in the visibility formula, but like I said it doesn't work.

But yet when this is used with a timer like so:

```
If(Timer1_1!Value=5000, true)
```

After you navigate to the page and 5 seconds later the button appears and it works great.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
If(Text1!Text="test1234", true)
```

did the job!

-Sean

Also if you want to clear out the password "InputText" then you'll have to do something like this:

```
Navigate(Screen1, ScreenTransition!Fade);UpdateContext({text_pwd: "abc"});UpdateContext({text_pwd: ""})
```

Put that on the button for navigate and it will navigate to the "Screen1" and clear out the password text, then change the *Default* property of the password "InputText" to *text_pwd* or what ever you would like to name it.

Goodluck!
-Sean